# Observable from callback method

Tags: f#, observable, reactive-programming, system.reactive, rx.net

Let say I have a class which iherits legacy API and overrides a virtual method which is called when something happens

```
type MyClass() as this =
    let somethingObservable: IObservable<Something> = ...

    override _.OnSomething(s: Something) = ...
```

How can I translate each invokation of OnSomething to a notification of somethingObservable?

That's probably a simple question, but I could not find a way to do it properly (should I use not advised ISubject?). Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a subject like this is fine, and ensures correctness in the implementation. 
Here's an example using `FSharp.Control.Reactive`, which gets you the idiomatic way of writing this.

```
type MyClass() =
    inherit Legacy()
    let somethingObservable = 
        Subject.broadcast

    override _.OnSomething s = 
        somethingObservable |> Subject.onNext s |> ignore

    member _.AsObservable = 
        somethingObservable |> Observable.asObservable
```

You can also use `new Subject<_>` and its methods, same thing.
In some assembly if you'd prefer not to take on the `System.Reactive` dependency, F# also natively supports `IObservable` through events.

```
type MyClassEvt() =
    inherit Legacy()
    let event = new Event<_>()

    override _.OnSomething s = 
        event.Trigger s

    member _.AsObservable = 
        event.Publish :> IObservable<_>
```